# Cron job setup and automatic execution on server

Tags: php, cron

I have a situation where there are thousands of products where each product price continuously check and up to date with other sites. For fast processing i created multiple links. each link process 50 records only. and divided all links on 5 servers for fast processings.

I setup cron job for each link which should be processed after every 12 hours. but there should be 15 min gap between two link processing time on single server.

As there are huge no of links generated manually. (about 230 links or more), it can't be easy for me to setup cron job for each link manually.

For this reason i want to write dynamic php script to generate 230 crone job links.

I write txt file and generate script for cron job about 230 links here is sample example.

```
0 0,12 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f http://xxx.us/amazon/proc.php?  id=1&size=50
15 0,12 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f http://xxx.us/amazon/proc.php?id=2&size=50
30 0,12 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f http://xxx.us/amazon/proc.php?id=3&size=50
45 0,12 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f http://xxx.us/amazon/proc.php?id=4&size=50
.....
230 crone job links
```

Is there any way i can execute dynamically generated script on server to automatically install all cron jobs instead of doing it manually which took lot of time even in start and also if in case i need modification in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will flood the crontab and will do no good, especially if you get more jobs in the future. I would recommend to use just one script running all 15 minutes and check the time inside the script. Process your links according with wether it's 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes.

Once you get more links you can either process more of them in each run or lower the time between calls by simply changing one line in the crontab and your statement switch.

Comment: thanks, i extended your logic and it ease my development effort and make cron job restricted to only one link.

Answer (score 1):

I would use just one cron-job and a shell script to loop through all your php calls.

If you are on linux, it would be something like (simple untested example...):

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 1; i < 5; i++))
do
   /usr/local/bin/php -f http://xxx.us/amazon/proc.php?id=[$i]&size=50
   echo "Finished batch: $i"
done
```

And change `5` to whatever you want.